# Can I use GroupDocs to add e-signature functionality to CRM

Tags: php, crm, saas, groupdocs, e-signature

I am investigating the possibility of adding e-signature functionality to a CRM SaaS.

I am having some difficulty understanding the process, and how to use GroupDocs to accomplish this.

The goal is to have users upload a PDF in the CRM, and email it to their customers to sign. The email will contain a link to a page with a signature pad to collect a signature image from the signer.

Can someone give me an overview of how GroupDocs could be used to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

[Groupdocs.Signature Cloud SDK for PHP](https://products.groupdocs.cloud/signature/php) support signing all popular file formats using digital, Barcode, image, QR code, stamp and text signature types. Currently, it supports signing documents from cloud storage( Groupdocs Cloud, Amazon S3, DropBox, FTP Storage, Google Drive and Windows Azure Storage). However, in near future, we will provide support to sign documents without storage i.e. signing from a stream( i.e. request body).

So for now you can follow this workflow to sign your PDF document with GroupDocs.Signature Cloud.

- [upload](https://docs.groupdocs.cloud/signature/working-with-file-api/) your PDF document to cloud storage
- [upload](https://docs.groupdocs.cloud/signature/working-with-file-api/) the signature image(collected from the signature pad) to cloud storage
- [sign](https://docs.groupdocs.cloud/signature/sign-document-with-image-signature/) PDF document with the signature image
- [download](https://docs.groupdocs.cloud/signature/working-with-file-api/) signed PDF from cloud storage and proceed as per your workflow.

P.S: I'm developer evangelist at GroupDocs.